# Error building tensorflow using bazel in a docker container

Tags: windows, tensorflow, bazel

I installed docker toolbox in windows, and I also pulled images for tensorflow and bazel.
When i run bazel in docker as follows:

```
docker run -it insready/bazel:latest bash
```

the bazel runs, but no tensorflow in workplace, as I "git clone tensorflow", i can run as:

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference
```

erros occured that the protobuf file not download!
How can i optimize the tensorflow model (.pb file) with bazel tools in order to build the app in a android envionment?

```
root@8f43a8b6c598:/usr/src/app/tensorflow# bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:o
ptimize_for_inference
Extracting Bazel installation...
..............................
ERROR: /usr/src/app/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/BUILD:147:1: error loadin
g package 'tensorflow/core': Encountered error while reading extension file 'pro
tobuf.bzl': no such package '@protobuf//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/u_apply_patch(repo_ctx, repo_ctx.attr.patch_file) line 119
        File "/u_execute_and_check_ret_code(repo_ctx, cmd).bzl", line 110, in _a
pply_patFile "/usr/src/app/tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl", line 94, in _ex
ecute_and_check_fail("Non-zero return code({1}) when ..., <2 more arguments>))
Non-zero return code(256) when executing 'patch -p1 -d /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel
_root/fcc55b35a14d93d1b456fb4b036f6add/external/protobuf -i /usr/src/app/tensorf
low/third_party/protobuf/add_noinlines.patch':
Stdout:
Stderr: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "patch" (in directory "/root/.ca
che/bazel/_bazel_root/fcc55b35a14d93d1b456fb4b036f6add/external/protobuf"): erro
r=2, No such file or directory and referenced by '//tensorflow/python/tools:opti
mize_for_inference'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference' fai
led; build aborted.
```

Comment: i also copy the files in docker to cotainer as "docker cp tensorflow ***:/tensorflow/", but when i run the bazel, i can not see this file.

Comment: Instead of comment your own question, you could [edit] the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message:

```
Cannot run program "patch"
```

Maybe patch is not installed, try `apt-get install patch` ?